# Qmake copy multiple files while building

Tags: c++, qmake

I have a list of files in my Qmake project. And I want them copied in build directory at build time.

My qmake file is below

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    input1 \
    input2 \
    input3 \
```

I'm using Linux. I've read a few stack overflow questions and googled about my problem but cannot find the exact solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can be done using `for()` loop. You may need to adjust the `BUILD_DIR` variable. The "other" files are takes from the current directory.

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    input1 \
    input2 \
    input3 \

BUILD_DIR = build

for(file, OTHER_FILES) {
    eval($${file}.depends = $$file)
    eval($${file}.target = $$BUILD_DIR/$$file)
    eval($${file}.commands = cp $$file $$BUILD_DIR/)

    QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += $${file}
    PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$BUILD_DIR/$$file
}
```